# Upload package to pypi moans "must use HTTPS"

Tags: pypi

When executing this from the command-line of within my package:

```
python setup.py sdist bdist_egg upload
```

I get:

> Server response (403): Must access using HTTPS instead of HTTP

This used to work many times until now. Searching for the err-msg didn't give me helpful infos, has anyone a clue what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Use [twine](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twine/) for uploading distributions to pypi.

---

Are you using a .pypirc file?

If you are maybe change the urls to point to the https links?

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
  pypi
  pypitest

[pypi]
repository=https://pypi.python.org/pypi
username=your_username
password=your_password

[pypitest]
repository=https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
username=your_username
password=your_password
```

Comment: Yes I do, I tried many variants, one like yours just without the pypitest-part, would that make a difference? I'll try that later anyways, thanks!

Comment: Browsing Github found this issue with a proposed solution. I think the proposed solution should work for you. https://github.com/mardiros/pyshop/issues/68.

Comment: I saw that issue, too, but didn't understand it. However upgrading setuptools let the error disappear, but still no new version available at pypi.

Answer (score 0):

Updating setuptools let's the error dissapear:

```
pip install setuptools -U
```

Then running the upload-command ends with:

> Submitting dist/my.packagename-1.3.tar.gz to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
>
> error: None

But still, no new version is available at pypi.

Comment: o.O wow. Okay. Can you try the upload with twine? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twine/

Comment: @Colwin That worked, thank you. Updated your answer accordingly and accepted it.